# Execute a short background task in a rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, background-process

Let's take an example :

```
class UsersController
  def create
    User.create(...)
    PushService.push('you have a new friend') # Can take 1/2 seconds
  end
end
```

I want to execute a short task (Pushing some users) in the controller. I don't do it synchronously because it can increase the response time, but using `Resque`, `Sidekiq` or `DelayJob` seems exaggerated to me.

What would be the consequences of using a simple `Thread`, is that a good practice to use it in a controller? Do you have other alternatives?

Comment: By using sidekiq, You can run class methods from single line code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting a thread it not that bad for simple things, but you'll have to manually handle all possibilities of it going wrong (freezing, exceptions)

You might want to look into using sucker_punch ActiveJob backend - it runs tasks inprocess, but you'll have the benefits of activejob (easier testing, generators etc.) and ability to switch to other backend later, if needed.

Comment: I don't understand the difference between sucker_punch and ActiveJob. They seem to do the same thing, storing the queue in RAM. Do you recommend one over an other?

Comment: @JérômeBoé One is backend to another. Like MySQL/postgres to ActiveRecord